# How to get ONLY the DOM structure of a page using jQuery $.get()

Tags: dom, jquery

Using jQuery 1.7.3

I've recently replaced a `$.load();` call with a `$.get();` in one of my scripts to take advantage of request aborting and other cool features - so I'm requesting a normal (php in this case) html page rather than a file that returns JSON or XML.

But I've noticed that a script error on the page you are loading - for example `onError='myFunction(this);'` inline scripts that call a function not defined on page1 but present on page2, can throw an error (in this case, `undefined function myFunction`) on page1. Also I see the images are requested too.

My use case is that I need one div worth of data from the new page, not the whole thing and certainly not the images - is there a way to get jQuery to request only the markup and not 'follow' the image links, nor attempt to run any inline scripts?

Example:

```
Page1:
$.get('page2', {someData:123}, function(data){
    var myDiv = $('#myDiv', data); //get the div I want from the response

    //but at this point the browser has run the inline 
    //scripts and requested the images :(
    //do something with the (very expensive) data

    $('body').append(myDiv);
});

Page2:
<div id='myDiv'>
  <!-- some dynamic data that changes over time -->
</div>
```

There are some concerns about whether I should just write (yet another) file I can query with JSON to get the data I need, then parse it in the script and generate the markup, etc etc, but sufficed to say in this use case that would be far more trouble than it's worth, especially considering I'd be replicating code too.

With regards the inline scripts, I can (and have, as a workaround) just define the function on page1 to avoid the error.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this that I eventually found is pretty simple - when you make an AJAX request to a page, send in an extra parameter that stops your page from outputting data you don't need.

```
Page1:
$.get('page2', {someData:123, ajax:true}, function(data){
    var myDiv = $('#myDiv', data); //get the div I want from the response
    $('body').append(myDiv);
});

Page2:
<?php if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) { ?>
  <div id='myDiv'>
    <!-- some dynamic data that changes over time -->
  </div>
  <?php exit(); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
  //show the page as normal
<?php } ?>
```

This approach is a pain to implement, but does the job and is nice and efficient when you have a very big search page that does all sorts of extra stuff, but all you want is the next page of results.

Answer (score 1):

You could exclude nodes from the selector:

```
var myDiv = $(data).find('#myDiv').find('*').not('img, script');
```

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: that's essentially what $('#myDiv', data); does. it doesn't matter whether I *select* the images from the page, the problem is that the browser actually attempts to *load* them. I see what you were thinking though, I'll give it a try anyway :)

Comment: First of all: I have added `.find('*')`, cause the .not() would have no effect on the `#myDiv`. Is the browser loading the images, if you not output the response?

Comment: the reason I say the browser loads the images is that I get 404 and 403 errors in the console for placeholders etc that would return those errors on loading that page. Also, I tried this but didn't see any change in behaviour - your selector does work though

Comment: also - making the request to the page is what does it. I can see in firebug's net panel requests for .swf and image files. However no script or css files - inline scripts still get executed though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do the ajax request with `$.ajax()` and set `dataType` to `text`? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: +1 for tenacity (and good suggestions). this looked like it should work, but still seeing extra GET requests for the images after loading page2 - I also tried setting dataType to html after reading the docs you linked - same result. I suppose I can live with it, it just seems wasteful